# Does disabling Network adapter on virtual box stop all networking between guest and host os

Tags: networking, virtualbox

If I unselect - `Enable Network Adapter` in my virtual box. This option is under the Settings->Network
Will the guest OS be able to communicate with the Host OS ?

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the guest Network Adapter, yes, that stops communication between guest and host. There is no other way to connect the two machines.

You can manually transfer data by USB key but that is entirely manual.

Comment: Is there way to disable network Adapter while inside guest OS and enable it again ? Rather than from the virtual box ->setting->Network option. Also how can I ensure that there is no communication possible between host and guest os ? could a failure of `ping` from guest to host os ensure that ?

Comment: You can use the network tools of the operating system to both disable and enable. You can turn off the guest network adapter in the VBOX menu (that is what I see in virutalizing apps). Try that and be sure networking remains off in the guest.

Comment: This disabling of Network Adapter. Is it like disabling the interface through which all network communication happens ?

Comment: You need to the the VBOX disabling and then test it. The disabling is similar yes, but you need to test it.